# Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined in AWS CHIME

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, vhosts, aws-chime-sdk

I am trying to run the AWS CHIME demo project locally. it is working fine if I doesn't change the const `host ="127.0.0.1:8080"` in the `server.js file`. But when changing the host to local IP to virtualization of host it throws an error after

[image: this error]

the error showed to me

[image: this error]

> Unable to find meeting
>   There was an issue finding that meeting.
>
> The meeting may have already ended, or your authorization may have expired.
>   Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined